# How to refresh JS datatables using AJAX

Tags: ajax, datatables

I am using AJAX to load (and subsequently refresh) a JS datatable (v1.10.0). I don't think I'm doing this properly because while I can get the initial table to load, subsequent AJAX requests do not update the table.

I've tried various combinations of the .clear(), .draw() and .rows.add() JS Datatables methods, but nothing seems to work.

jquery code below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#results').html('<table id="table-output" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>');

    var table_config = {
        "bDestroy": true,
        "paging": false,
        "language": {
            "zeroRecords": "No results found",
            "processing": "<div align='center'><img src='/static/ajax-loader.gif'></div>",
            "loadingRecords": "<div align='center'><img src='/static/ajax-loader.gif'></div>"
        }
    };       

    $("form").submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var form_data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeArray());

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: /the_url,
            data: form_data,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {

                table_config.data = response.data;
                table_config.columns = response.columns;

                $('#table-output').dataTable(table_config);

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX call is succeeding?

Comment: Yep, checked the response in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Modifying the success function as follows works:

```
success: function(response) {
                    $('#results').html('<table id="table-output" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>');

                    table_config.columns = response.columns;

                    var table = $('#table-output').DataTable(table_config);
                    table.clear();
                    table.rows.add(response.data);
                    table.draw();

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
var table1 = $('#youtblename').DataTable();
var pathp = "/server_processing_pie.php";

tablel.clear();
tablel.draw();
tablel.ajax.url(pathp).load();
```

Comment: this wouldn't work for me as you are using datatable's ajax method instead of jquery's (a requirement)